# Storing database config details in AWS Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, configuration-files, aws-parameter-store

I would like to store the following database config details in the Parameter Store for secure access:

```
databaseUser = 'user'
databasePassword = 'password'
databaseName = 'name'
databaseHost = 'host'
```

I know I can save individual parameters by key value, but it is possible to store all parameters in one entry. For example, the key being config and the value being a dictionary of the key/value pairs.  Or should I store them in 4 different entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it either way imo, but I would personally lean to a single entry.

Doesn't look like you would really ever use just one of the 4 params without the others, so to me it looks like a single key/entry.

Would be no harm either way, but 4 entries is just a bit more work to use with no benefit.